# Program wont print all lines from txt file

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Wrote this program which should be able to print out all lines from a txt file, but it only prints one, been looking at it for 1 hour now and i cant find the mistake, any help would be appriciated! :)

1        16.07.2011 kl. 17.00    OB - FCN      2 - 0      6.965
1        17.07.2011 kl. 14.00    FCM - SIF     1 - 2      5.370
1        17.07.2011 kl. 16.00    ACH - HBK     3 - 0      2.227
1        17.07.2011 kl. 16.00    SDR - FCK     0 - 2      4.992
the first 4 lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LGT 200
#define NAME_MAX 200
#define TEAM_MAX 200

struct team{
char name[NAME_MAX];
int five_or_more_goals;
};
typedef struct team team;

void read_data_1(const char *file_name, team teams[]){
FILE *ifp;
char team1[NAME_MAX];
char team2[NAME_MAX];
int goal1, goal2;
int dag, month, year;
double clock;
int attendance;
int round;
team local_match;

ifp = fopen(file_name, "r");

while (fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %d\n", &round, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10){
    printf("runde %d den %d %d %d klokken %.2lf, mellem %s og %s endte %d - %d %d så kampen\n", round, dag, month, year, clock, team1, team2, goal1, goal2, attendance);
    }

fclose(ifp);

   }

  int main(void) {
  team all_matches_teams[TEAM_MAX];
  read_data_1("superliga-2011-2012", all_matches_teams);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without seeing your file. Actually, not even the whole file: the first three or four lines should be enough.

Comment: I would remove the `\n` from the end of the format string -- it's going to be skipped anyway, and the last line may not contain one.

Comment: What does fscanf return the second time?

Comment: Ah sorry, adding some of the text from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attendance value at the end of each line of input is causing you the problem.  You'll need to either parse it as a float or two decimals separated by a period, not just a single decimal.  It should work with the code changes below, assuming attendance never reaches a million:

```
int valuesRead;
int attendance;
int attend1, attend2;
[...]
while ((valuesRead = fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %d.%d\n", &round, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attend1, &attend2)) >= 10){
    if (valuesRead == 11)
        attendance = attend1 * 1000 + attend2;
    else
        attendance = attend1;
    printf("runde %d den %d %d %d klokken %.2lf, mellem %s og %s endte %d - %d %d så kampen\n", round, dag, month, year, clock, team1, team2, goal1, goal2, attendance);
}
```

Comment: I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped)
checking the scanf and printf and see if the matches

Comment: Seems like I cant get it to run, still segmentation fault(core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys, i got it working now, by just changing the attendance variable to a double and it works fine, heres the code again, if anyone has any tips to write it smarter, do let me know ! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LGT 200
#define NAME_MAX 200
#define TEAM_MAX 200

struct team{
char name[NAME_MAX];
int five_or_more_goals;
};
typedef struct team team;

void read_data_1(const char *file_name, team teams[]){
FILE *ifp;
char team1[NAME_MAX];
char team2[NAME_MAX];
int goal1, goal2;
int dag, month, year;
double clock;
double attendance;
int round;
team local_match;

ifp = fopen(file_name, "r");

while (fscanf(ifp, "%d %d.%d.%d kl. %lf %4s - %4s %d - %d %lf\n", &round, &dag, &month, &year, &clock, team1, team2, &goal1, &goal2, &attendance) == 10){
    printf("runde %d den %d %d %d klokken %.2lf, mellem %s og %s endte %d - %d %.3lf så kampen\n", round, dag, month, year, clock, team1, team2, goal1, goal2, attendance);
    }

fclose(ifp);

    }

  int main(void) {
  team all_matches_teams[TEAM_MAX];
  read_data_1("superliga-2011-2012", all_matches_teams);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Glad you're figuring it out, but one comment: At the moment if the  attendance is a value under 1000, say 'x', your printed attendance is x.000.  That was the reason I thought to handle the values as integers, though I imagine my posted answer should be made more robust.

Comment: Ah I see, can see that could cause problems, but thank god theres no where the attendance is under 1000 hehe :) im still new to c, but thank you alot for your input

Comment: Oh perfect.  I wasn't sure about the constraints so that's why I didn't want to go overboard, but that's great, I'm glad you got a solution! :)